# How to copy files async (or parallel)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, file-copying

I'm trying to learn using async/await methods in C#. I have the following simple task:
Copy 2 files from one Windows-PC to another (both one the same local network). In reality, there can be about 1000 files, but for simplicity, I reduce it to two.
My code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var destinationPath = @"path\to\destination\folder";
        List<string> filePaths = new()
        {
            @"\\remote-pc\c$\files\file1",
            @"\\remote-pc\c$\files\file2",
        };
        
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (string path in filePaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start copy {Path.GetFileName(path)}");
            using var sourceStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
            using var destinationStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(path)), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
            var task = sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream).ContinueWith(_ => {
                Console.WriteLine($"End copy {Path.GetFileName(path)}");
            });
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs);
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, async / await must be used in I / O-bound operations - just this case (or am I mistaken?). When executing the

```
sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream)
```

line, the calling thread will be freed to perform the next operation (apparently this is true, so when running at the same time
there are two WriteLine's about the beginning of copying files).
However, by analyzing the code execution time (elapsedMs), which is ~30 s. for two files, I conclude that the files are not copied in parallel at all. When you start copying each file separately, the execution time is ~20 s. and ~6 s. for each file respectively. Therefore, with "parallel copying" I expect the total execution time = the time of copying the largest file.

Please help me understand my reasoning.

Comment: *"I expect the total execution time = the time of copying the largest file."* - Why?  Suppose you have 1 file that is 10MB and 1,000 files which are 1MB each.  The total time to copy these files would not be the time to copy a single 10MB file.  You don't get disk operations for free just because they're queued up in parallel by the application.

Comment: You're copying files from a remote network, not just from another local folder. The time required to copy the files is limited by the network bandwidth *and* the remote machine's load. If you use a slow NAS you may get *very* slow transfer speeds no matter the network. Besides, the code works only by accident, because the streams get disposed  you posted will fail because the streams get disposed inside the `foreach` block. Extract the copying code into another asynchronous method at least and remove `ContinueWith`

Comment: Starting 2 copy operations splits the bandwidth in two. Starting 1000 means each copy gets 1/1000th the bandwidth. The fact that copying 2 files concurrently is slower than sequential copying means there are both network and server issues. Once you create a separate async method, eg `FileCopyAsync`, you can use an `ActionBlock` or `Parallel.ForEachAsync` with a MaxDegreeOfParallelism setting that won't flood the network or server

Comment: ^^ That being said: Even in the local FileSystem, you wouldn't want to start 1000 concurrent copy-operations at once..

Comment: Also you are disposing the  streams before the ciopy is finished. Move the `using` *inside* the task, and don't use `ContinueWith`, just use `await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really true that the total time taken will be the size of the largest file, because in most cases you will bottleneck the reading or writing disks. You may still get better performance, but you might want to limit the maxmimium number of parallel copies.

Either way, your code is not correct. Do not use `ContinueWith`, use `await` instead. And don't dispose the streams outside the task, otherwise the copying may fail, instead make an `async` lambda and dispose inside it.

```cs
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Start copy {Path.GetFileName(path)}");
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using var sourceStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
        using var destinationStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(path)), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
        await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
        Console.WriteLine($"End copy {Path.GetFileName(path)}");
    });
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```